# VM - custom payment plugin and payment methods do not work

Tags: joomla-3.4, plugin, virtuemart

I can't make my VM payment plugin to work at `joomla v3.5.0 and virtuemart v3.0.12`. 
I've install a custom payment plugin. Initially it worked, yet the same time other payment methods (when invoked) were wrong directed to my custom plugin payment gateway.
[image]

Therefore I've slightly changed it. And now when the plugin is installed and turned on in admin panel, none of payment methods work. As I process with a cart (enter data, choose *any* payment method, etc.) and click on 'process' btn. the following error transpires:  *Error 500. Site  can't process your request*.

Also, the plugin's payment methods settings are not saved in admin (besides defaults):
[image]

how to break thru, any hints? You may ask additionally questions to clarify the case.

### Update

I've not done many edits of the plugin code. Mainly small edits were in manifest file `latcard.xml` to make parameters savable. But to no positive result.

### Manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<extension version="1" type="plugin" group="vmpayment" method="upgrade">
<name>VM - Payment, Latcard</name>

<creationDate>November 28 2015</creationDate>
<author>SIA LatCard</author>
<authorEmail>bbbb@latcard.lv</authorEmail>
<authorUrl>http://www.latcard.eu</authorUrl>
<author>LatCard AS</author>
<creationDate>November 2015</creationDate>
<copyright>Copyright SIA LatCard</copyright>
<license>http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-2.0.html GNU/GPL</license>
<version>1.0.0</version>
<description>
    <![CDATA[<a href="http://www.latcard.eu" target="_blank">LatCard</a> ]]>
</description>

<files>
    <filename plugin="latcard">latcard.php</filename>
    <filename>latcard.xml</filename>
    <filename>index.html</filename>
    <folder>latcard</folder>
    <filename>controller.php</filename>     
    <folder>views</folder>
</files>

<vmconfig>
        <fields name="params">
                <fieldset name="basic" addfieldpath="/plugins/vmpayment/latcard/latcard/fields">
                    <fields addpath="/plugins/vmpayment/latcard/elements"/>
                    <fields addpath="/plugins/vmpayment/latcard/latcard/elements"/>
                    <fields addpath="/administrator/components/com_virtuemart/elements"/>


                    <field name="merchant" type="text" size="10" default="" label="Merchant ID" description="Merchant ID"/>
                    <field name="site_id" type="text" size="10" default="" label="Site ID" description="Site ID"/>
                    <field name="password" type="text" size="10" default="" label="SOAP password" description="SOAP password"/>

                    <field name="secure_3d" type="radio" default="1" label="3D Secure" description="3D Secure">
                            <option value="0" >No</option>
                            <option value="1" >Yes</option>
                    </field>
                </fieldset>
        </fields>
</vmconfig>
```

Comment: Show your changes to the plugin. You may have a PHP error in your modified plugin, which leads to the 500 error

Comment: @fruppel, please see my update.

Answer (score 0):

500 error may come from your plugin's PHP code.

I got the same problem that my plugin's configuration was not saved. After debugging in Virtuemart code, I found out that I needed this function in my plugin's class:

```
function plgVmDeclarePluginParamsPaymentVM3(&$data) {
    return $this->declarePluginParams('payment', $data);
}
```

Ensure that you already setup for parameters and pass them to Virtuemart in `__contstruct` function. For example:

```
public function __construct(&$subject, $config)
{
    parent::__construct($subject, $config);

    $this->_loggable = true;
    $this->tableFields = array_keys($this->getTableSQLFields());
    $this->_tablepkey = 'id';
    $this->_tableId = 'id';

    $varsToPush = [
        'my_param' => array('', 'char'),
    ];

    $this->setConfigParameterable($this->_configTableFieldName, $varsToPush);
}
```